# Linq To Entity - Filter Relational As Well

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables.
Table 1 and Table 2. They have one to many relation. I'm trying to do a query like below. It works fine with finding the result. I mean if it cannot find any result according to the params i got null value as usual. However it brings all Table 2 results all the time in Table 1 class and I do want to get only Table 2 results according to the query.

```
dc.Table1s.SingleOrDefault(t1 => t1.SearchField1 == param1 
                           && t1.Table2s.Any(t2 => t2.SearchField2 == param2 
                                          && t2.SearchField3 == param3));
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE @6/8/2011
Can you try this so that you get Filtered Table2s in Table1

```
var result = from  t1 in Table1s
             where t1.key == t2.key && t1.SearchField1 == param1
             select new Table1s //creating new Table1s Object with Filtered Table2s values
                    {
                        key = t1.key,
                        SearchField1 = t1.SearchField1
                        //set all other Table1s propeties from t1
                        ...
                        Table2s = t1.Table2s.Where( x=> x.SearchField2 == param2 && x.SearchField3 == param3)
                    };


-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since you are checking for "Any", you are just getting Table1 Entity which matches your condition. Table1s.Table2s gives you all related entries. You need to Filter it again

```
dc.Table1s.SingleOrDefault(t1 => t1.SearchField1 == param1 
                           && t1.Table2s.Any(t2 => t2.SearchField2 == param2 
                                          && t2.SearchField3 == param3));
```

while you need to fetch Table2s for Table1 matching your search condition,

```
var table2s = table1.Table2s.Where(t2 => t2.SearchField2 == param2 && t2.SearchField3 == param3);
```

if you directly need Table2s, you can do:

```
var result = from t1 in Table1s
             from t2 in Table2s
             where t1.key == t2.key && t1.SearchField1 == param1
                                    && t2.SearchField2 == param2 
                                    && t2.SearchField3 == param3
             select t2;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I do want 1 result and it is Table1 class. Then when i go to Table1.Table2s i should see filtered data not all of them... :(

Comment: Again thank you very much for the answer. The one you wrote is my worst case scenario. I do not prefer it because i do not want to set all properties of Table 1. Did you understand my obsession? :)

Comment: I guess my main problem is LazyLoading :(